# C# OleDbCommand text: special chars and Excel range reference

Tags: excel, oledbcommand

I’m about to essentially kill myself headbanging trying to read data from Excel with OleDB in C#.
My spreadsheet contains two tabs named exactly as:

- FC One
- FC Two, Three, 4Four

The data I need to read is located in the range A14:AG140. Thus, I fire a command

```
"SELECT * From [FC One$A14:AG140]"
```

– and get the results I need for the first tab. How do I spell the command for the second tab? Below are the options I tried, and none of them succeeded:

```
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four'$A14:AG140]"
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four'$!A14:AG140]"
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four$'A14:AG140]"
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four$'!A14:AG140]"
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four$!A14:AG140']"
"SELECT * From ['FC Two, Three, 4Four$A14:AG140']"
```

Comment: How about this: `SELECT * FROM [name-of-sheet$cell-reference]` and if your sheet naem has spaces, wrap it in single quotes: `SELECT * FROM ['name of sheet'$cell-reference]`

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've made it. Strangely enough, the quotes were not necessary at all. This stuff worked:

```
SELECT * From [FC Two, Three, 4Four$A14:AG14]
```